# npx is not running an can't create nextjs app

Tags: node.js, next.js

```
PS D:\Priyanshu\share_prompts> npx create-next-app@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\priya\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\priya\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-21T06_03_55_728Z-debug-0.log
```

I just couldn't what the problem is

Comment: Then it's time to read the complete log of this run, which you can find in `C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-21T06_03_55_728Z-debug-0.log`. The error you're showing says it's trying to run a program called `lstat`, but it doesn't exist

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No `lstat` is a syscall that tries to get the statistics of a file or directory. The directory not to be found is `c:\users\priya\AppData\Roaming\npm` ..

Comment: can i get the solution

Comment: How did you install Node?